# Automatically updating a value through a OptionMenu tkinter object

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to write a tkinter app that will automatically update a value based on the current state of the OptionMenu object. Here's what I have so far

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def show():
  myLabel=Label(root,text=clicked.get()).pack()

clicked=StringVar()
clicked.set("1")

drop = OptionMenu(root,clicked,"1","2","3")
drop.pack()

myButton = Button(root,text="show selection",command=show)

root.mainloop()
```

In this version, the text can only be updated by clicking a button. How can I make the text update automatically, without this "middle man"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign `clicked` to the `textvariable` of the `Label`, then whenever an option is selected, the label will be updated:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

clicked = tk.StringVar(value="1")

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, "1", "2", "3")
drop.pack()

tk.Label(root, textvariable=clicked).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this one!

Answer (score 1):

After changing some things, i got it working.

It is better to use the `config()` function to change item's attributes, and another important thing is to not `pack()` the objects (the Label, in this case) in the same line that the variable declaration.

Like so, you'll be able to change the text. Here is your code updated!

```py
from tkinter import *

def show():
    myLabel.config(text = clicked.get())

root = Tk()
clicked=StringVar( value="1")

myLabel=Label(root, text="click the button at the bottom to see this label text changed")
myLabel.pack()

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "1","2","3")
drop.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="show selection", command=show)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```