# How to delete and redisplay a tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I have a Dropbox and I want to print out a selected fruit option it works, But I want it to delete the previously displayed fruit and put the new selected one in it's place but instead it just displays the new one under the first

here's the program

```
   fruits=["apple",
        "mango",
        "pear",
        "orange"]
clicked=StringVar()
clicked.set(fruits[0])

drop=OptionMenu(root,clicked,*fruits)
drop.pack()

def Print():         
display=Label(root,text=clicked.get()).pack()

button=Button (root,text="Print",command=Print)
```

Comment: Similar question [automatically-updating-a-value-through-a-optionmenu-tkinter-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347255/automatically-updating-a-value-through-a-optionmenu-tkinter-object).

Comment: `config` method would help you?

Comment: @cool cloud how do you use it

Comment: `display.config(text=clicked.get())` try saying this after asignment of `display`.

Comment: Ill add it as an answer?

Comment: ya you should add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does this, you created each time an new instance of the Label class by calling tk.Label(). The easiest solution would be to add your variable as text variable to your label.

`Display = Label(root, textvariable=clicked)`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603371